# How to compare the local version of the project with latest repository version?

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

IDE: IntelliJ IDEA 10.5

VCS: Subversion

I can do updates and commits, but the comparison functions is not active.

[image]

Comment: May you have some conflicts? Resolve Text Conflict and Mark Resolved are enable..

Comment: It's not supported yet, see the related issue: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-55335